# Cannot update from version 10.10 to 11.4 because natty unavailable

Tags: 10.10, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

I have the Maverick release of Ubuntu 10.10 and the only release that is suggested to me is Natty 11.04. But the files cannot be retrieved from servers to install Natty because as you can see here, they don't exist anymore... http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/. Ubuntu thus tells me I must have a connection problem because it cannot find files. (which is not the case).

Do you know if I can manually download, open and execute the files from another release (Oneiric for example)? 
Thanks a lot in advance,

Pauline

Answer (score 1):

Support of Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Nehwal has been closed as per its cycle expires. You should move to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS which will be supported till April 2017.

Using packages of other version may break your system with it.

Comment: But I read that I can only update from a version to the version immediately after...
In the "Update Manager", I don't have any other choice than 11.04...

Comment: Update your system , You will get notification that New LTS precise is available.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked using Torrent Search and found a number of torrents that have 11.04 available (both 64-bit and 32-bit and for different platforms.) You can find out about Torrent Search [here](http://torrent-search.sourceforge.net/).  If you're comfortable using torrents, they are often quite fast (use one with lots of "seeders").